# How to set JAVA HOME in Ant build.xml

Tags: java, xml, ant

I have the following build.xml file and i want to set JAVA HOME path but i don't know where to write and what to write. Does anyone wants to help me?

```
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
</target>

<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="mapreduce.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Master"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run">
    <java jar="mapreduce.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create a env.bat file (if your on windows)

inside you would include this:

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\java\jdk1.5
```

then you would do something like this:

```
env.bat

ant -f build.xml all
```

Comment: I want to set JAVA HOME from within build.xml. Is that possible?

Comment: ANT runs on Java as well, so the only way to change the JVM within the build file is to specify it on the "java" or "javac" tasks. See: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html for an example.